# What date was Kibrot Hattaavah?

Tags: history, calendar, behaalotcha-parsha

Are there any sources that give the date for the incident in Kibroth Hattaavah recorded in B'Midbar Chapter 11? I am trying to figure out if it happened on a particular mo'ed or any significant date.

Comment: Hi Kovesh, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Is [this account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2524/kovesh) yours? You can ask StackExchange to merge them by following the instructions [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 3):

[Seder Olam Rabbah 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46769&st=&pgnum=40) says the Jews left Sinai on 20 Iyar of Year 2 after the Exodus, traveled to Kibrot Hattaavah, spent 30 days there (because that's how long they ate the quail for [Num 11:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0411.htm#20)), traveled to Chatzerot, spent 7 days there (because that's how long Miriam was expelled for [Num 12:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0412.htm#15)), traveled to Midbar Paran, arriving on 28 Sivan or the same year. That's a span of 38/39 days including both end dates to cover 37 days of encampment plus 3 travels (he doesn't mention if Iyar that year had 29 or 30 days).

So the fight probably took place 20, 21 or 22 Iyar.

Comment: A classic instance of Seder Olam assuming everything takes the absolute minimum possible amount of time to occur.

Comment: Doesn't Rashi on the Chumash give a very similar accounting of the days? I can't remember exactly where

Comment: @Menachem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_egg_dilemma

Comment: Probably so. Do you remember where the Rashi is?

Comment: @Menachem Nope. Sorry

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would this put them approximately at the sixth or seventh day of Pesach Sheni then, if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: @Kovesh I guess you can say that, expect there is no such thing. The Pesach Sheni offering has no associated Yom Tov, no prohibition on Chametz, nor does it continue for seven days.